# Creating Access table from text file

Tags: database, ms-access

I was wondering is it possible to create an Access Database table from a text file. 
For example a text file like this:

```
#Tom
Age:12 
Info: Tall
#Alice
Age: 20
Info: Nice
```

Should be converted to a table with 3 parameters (Name, Age and Info) containing the info of Tom and Alice. 
A different example would be the text file:

```
Tim
-------
A tall 12 years old. 
Good In basketball

Jak
-------
A short 30 years old guy. 
Bad at sports 
Bald
```

Which should be converted into a table containing 2 parameters-age and info. 
If coding is required I'd prefer using c# though Java is also an option.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: The shortest answer to all "is it possible" question is : YES!

Comment: Ok, how do I do this? The bigger problem is when I get into adding files with two columns of inputs like the one in the picture (for example a name header then beneath it, in the right column there's age and profile and in the left column height and weight)

Answer (score 0):

After a searching far and wide I found a solution. 
I loaded the text into a string in c#, than built an excel table using Microsofts API. 
After you've got an excel spreadsheet converting it to access is rather simple using Access' built-in functionaily

Answer (score 0):

It likely easer to do this in VBA – and you not need to write some messy c# (however, if you are actually familer with c#, then any compentent coder can EASY read some VBA and just type in c# line for line – assuming you are actually familer with C#.

So the VBA to import the first text file and write out the data to a table will look like this:

```
Sub Import1()

  Dim intfileH   As Integer
  Dim strBuf     As String
  Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strRec, vBuf, strRecDetail

  intfileH = FreeFile()
  Open "c:\test\text1.txt" For Input As #intfileH
  strBuf = Input(LOF(intfileH), #intfileH)
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblNames")

  vBuf = Split(strBuf, "#")
  For Each strRec In vBuf
     If strRec <> "" Then
        strRecDetail = Split(strRec, vbCrLf)
        With rst
           .AddNew
           !MyName = strRecDetail(0)
           !age = Split(strRecDetail(1), ":")(1)
           !Info = Split(strRecDetail(2), ":")(1)
           .Update
        End With
     End If
  Next

  rst.Close
  Close (intfileH)

End Sub
```

And for the second data, much the same, this will work:

```
Sub Import2()

  Dim intfileH   As Integer
  Dim strBuf     As String
  Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset
  Dim vBuf, strRec
  Dim i          As Integer

  intfileH = FreeFile()
  Open "c:\test\text2.txt" For Input As #intfileH
  strBuf = Input(LOF(intfileH), #intfileH)
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblNames")

  vBuf = Split(strBuf, vbCrLf)
  For i = 0 To UBound(vBuf)
     If vBuf(i) <> "" Then

        With rst
           .AddNew
           !MyName = vBuf(i)
           i = i + 2
           !age = Split(vBuf(i), " ")(2)
           i = i + 1
           !Info = vBuf(i)
           .Update
        End With
     End If
     i = i + 1
  Next

  rst.Close
  Close (intfileH)

End Sub
```